# applicationWillBecomeActive in MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to use the applicationDidBecomeActive method (and similar ones) - I can find plenty of examples in ObjC but none in Monotouch.
Have tried an override in AppDelegate and in UIViewController but the compiler finds no suitable method to override. So, how do I use this? 
I want to use it (in conjunction with a timer and IdleTimerDisabled) to stop the device from going to sleep for longer than usual (it's a stopwatch-type app). Maybe I'm on the wrong track.

Answer (score 2):

In your app delegate that inherits from `UIApplicationDelegate`, you can override these:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets called by iOS if the app is started from scratch and is not resumed from background.
/// We have 17 seconds to leave this methos before iOS will kill the app.
/// </summary>
public override bool FinishedLaunching ( UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions )

/// <summary>
/// Called if the app comes back from background or gets started. Triggered after FinishedLaunching().
/// </summary>
public override void OnActivated ( UIApplication application )

/// <summary>
/// Called if the application gets pushed to the background because the user hits the home button.
/// </summary>
public override void DidEnterBackground ( UIApplication application )

/// <summary>
/// Gets called if the app is resumed from background but NOT if the app starts first time.
/// </summary>
public override void WillEnterForeground ( UIApplication application )
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I think I asked the wrong question because I need to refresh my timer every time a button is touched, to keep the device awake a bit longer than usual. These overrides don't catch the correct events but you put me on the right track - I have now overridden TouchUpInside for all my buttons in the critical ViewController.